# Question about the behaviour of $f(z)=e^{1\over z-\sin z}$ at $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be given by $f(z)=e^{1\over z-\sin z}$. Then at $z = 0$, $f$:
>
> a) has a pole;
>
> b) has an essential singularity;
>
> c) has a removable singularity;
>
> d) is analytic.

as $z\to0\Rightarrow f(z)\to \infty$ We have $z=0$ is a pole?

Comment: Hint: What is a typical example of essential singularity, and how does this one differ from it?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex). I've fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Note that, $ z-\sin(z) \sim \frac{z^3}{3!}.$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal  so it must be an essesntial singularity.

Answer (score 1):

The function has an essential singularity at $z=0$. Write $z - \sin z = z  g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is analytic and nonvanishing at $z= 0$. So
$$
e^{\frac{1}{z - \sin z}} = e^{1/z}e^{1/g(z)}
$$
$e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$ and $e^{1/g(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$. Hence, the result.